# Wordpress language switcher doesn't work

Tags: php, options, multi-language, language

I am using WordPress version 4.4.2. The problem I am facing is, I can not change the site language form `Settings -> General -> Site language`.

If I change the language and hit save, the language does not update. I am using `Loco Translate` plugin. The plugin does not show any warning or error anywhere while translating.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you disable the plugins?

Comment: Only the translation plugin? Yes. I have also tested with some other plugins. The problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. There was no `languages` folder in `/wp-content` directory. I created a the directory and gave it proper permissions. Switching between languages worked after that.